# How to convert -0.0 to 0.0 in Java?

Tags: java, double, floating-accuracy

I am trying to write code that calculates the x and y coordinates of a circle given the radius and the x value for positive and negative y values. The code is below:

```
public class CirclePoints
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        double radius = 1;
        double x = 1;
        double y1 = 0;
        double y2 = 0;

        System.out.println("Points on a Circle with a Radius of 1.0");
        System.out.printf("%8s%8s%8s%8s", "x1", "y1", "x1", "y2");
        System.out.println("\n*************************************");
        for (x = 1; x>=-1;x -=0.1)
        {
            y1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 2) - (Math.pow(x, 2)));
            y2 = 0 - y1;
            System.out.printf("%8.2f%8.2f%8.2f%8.2f%n", x, y1, x, y2);
        }
    }
}
```

However when x coordinate equals -1, the negative y-value keeps on appearing as -0.00 no matter what I do (if statements, etc.). How can I get that one value in the printed table to be 0.00 and not -0.00? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use `Math.abs()`?

Comment: float and double in Java (and in most programming languages) are not exact.  You might want to look into using `BigDecimal` if you need exact math (including an exact zero value).

Comment: Note especially that `0.1` is not exactly representable in binary floating-point.

Comment: As an experiment, try adding `System.out.println(y2);` to the end of your loop body.  As others have mentioned, the floating-point representation of 0.1 is not exactly 0.1, so most likely, y1 and y2 are not exactly zero, but rather are very small values which are being rounded to two decimal places in your printf statement.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing that maybe suitable for you situation, you can check if absolute of it is less than something like *epsilon*, then that number may be zero. In my experience, *epsilon* maybe 1e-9, which is maybe enough for double.

**Updated from @PeterLawrey**: *epsilon* maybe **0.5e-2** for your *%8.2f*.

Comment: Since the OP is printing 2 decimal places, epsilon could be 0.5e-2

Comment: The 1e-9 is a reasonable figure for a wide variety of use cases without more information.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your code. It is the way calculations are being performed. See the following for more information.

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. ... Therefore the result of a
>   floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order to fit back
>   into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation. source:
>   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

You could always use Math.abs(value) to convert to a positive value.

Answer (score 0):

The floating point error in 0.1 (which has no finite approximation in their binary bits) will be multiplied twentyfold by the for loop.

Better behaviour can be expected from:

```
for (int x10 = 10; x10 >= -10; --x10) {
    x = x10 / 10.0;
```

Alternatively, if you are allowed to lie in your code, a small increasing correction for the `printf` will do:

```
       double ks = x + 0.00001;
       System.out.printf("%8.2f%8.2f%8.2f%8.2f%n", ks, y1, ks, y2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual value of `y` in your last iteration is about −2.1•10<sup>−8</sup> (sometimes shown as “-2.1e-8” or “-.000000021”). It appears as “-0.00” because you printed it with limited digits. This means the title of your question is off target: There is no `-0.0` to convert to `0.0`. You actually have a small negative value, not `-0`.

Other answers have suggested workarounds such as manually testing for a small value and replacing it with zero. While simple workarounds may work in the specific case you ask about, they are crude suggestions (such as take the absolute value or compare the absolute value to `0.5e-2`) with some flaws. For example, in the latter, is the proper test `Math.abs(y) <= 0.5e-2` or `Math.abs(y) < 0.5e-2`? Knowing whether to use `<` or `<=` requires knowing whether the source text `0.5e-2` is rounded up or down by the conversion to `double`. While this is easily determined for a specific value (by printing the full decimal value of the result of the conversion and visually comparing it to 0.05—then use `<=` if the result is below 0.05 and `<` if it is above), it is not so easy for values in general. One correct way to get a result formatted as you desire is to print to a buffer, then examine the result to see if it contains only zero digits, then, if it does, change the “-” to a space.

You should understand you are trying to correct the wrong thing here. There is nothing wrong with having a negative sign in front of zero. It is, however, a clue that other things are wrong in your program.

Java uses a binary-based format for floating-point numbers. In this format, 0.1 cannot be exactly represented, and that means the `x` value in your loop is never exactly a multiple of 0.1, except in the first iteration, when it starts with 1.

In Java, the source text `0.1` is converted to the nearest representable value, which is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. (Although I have written this value with many decimal digits, it is exactly a 53-bit integer divided by a power of two.) In the first iteration of your loop, `x` has the value 0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625. In the last iteration, it has the value −0.9999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375. Since this last value is not exactly −1, `y` is not exactly zero.

A serious problem here is that, when you write a loop like this, it is not guaranteed to end with a value near −1 if you use a different step size. Every time you perform floating-point arithmetic, the exact mathematical result is rounded to the nearest representable value, and that rounding may result in the value increasing or decreasing. Consider what happens when the loop is nearing its end, and the addition to `x` produces −1.0000000000000002… rather than −0.9999999999999997… Then the test `x >= -1` reports false, and the loop does not perform the final iteration you expected. For example, if the step size had been 0.01 instead of 0.1, the last iteration would have been with `x` equal to −0.99000000000000143440814781570225022733211517333984375. The last iteration, where `x` should be near −1, is never performed, because the actual computed value for `x` is −1.000000000000001332267629550187848508358001708984375.

A classic way to avoid that problem in simple loops is to use arithmetic with no rounding errors for the loop control, and then the scale the iterator value to the desired range. In your case, you could use:

```
for (i = 10; i >= -10; i -= 1)
{
    x = i / 10.;
    …
}
```

Here `i` can be an integer type or a floating-point type. Since all integers are representable in Java’s `double` up to 2<sup>53</sup>, there are no rounding errors in this range for arithmetic with integer results.

Answer (score 0):

To answer to the question posed in the title of this post: *how to  convert -0.0 to +0.0?* is done by adding +0.0 to your result.

`-0.0 + 0.0 == 0.0`

Adding zero is a no-op for all other cases. Only `-0.0` gets affected and becomes `+0.0`.